# strtotime returning wrong day

Tags: php, xml-parsing

When using the following

```
echo date('D',strtotime("2013-06-16T06:00:00-07:00"));
echo date('D',strtotime("2013-06-16T18:00:00-07:00"));
```

First it returns `Sun` and the Second returns `Mon`. I'm not really sure why or how to correct! The `Date:"2013-06-16T06:00:00-07:00"` is data I'm retrieving from a XML file. The `timestamp` has the correction for `UTC` at the end not sure if this is generating the error.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get expected results you should consider using [`DateTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
<?php
echo date('D',strtotime("2013-06-16T06:00:00-07:00")) . "\n";
echo date('D',strtotime("2013-06-16T18:00:00-07:00")) . "\n";;

$dt1 = new DateTime("2013-06-16T06:00:00-07:00");
$dt2 = new DateTime("2013-06-16T18:00:00-07:00");
echo $dt1->format('D') . "\n";
echo $dt2->format('D') . "\n";
```

Output

```
Sun
Mon
Sun
Sun
```

[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/6GtUQYmm)

Answer (score 1):

This is because The Date represents the time is in time zone specified in [`date.timezone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) settings.  So the timezone `-07:00` is parsed and converted back to `date.timezone` timezone.

To understand the idea just add `e` in the date string

```
echo date('D e',strtotime("2013-06-16T06:00:00-07:00"));
echo date('D e',strtotime("2013-06-16T18:00:00-07:00"));
```

See [example](http://ideone.com/pqtnzl).

Its better you use [DateTime()](http://php.net/DateTime). It does not have such limitation.